# Zooming on images smaller than the div dimensions and specifying the zoom extent using jQuery Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zooming

I'm trying to build a zoom feature on images. To do so, I'm using [Jquery Zoom](https://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/), the script is simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img')
    .wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>')
    .css('display', 'block')
    .parent()
    .zoom();
});
```

There are 2 problems with this:

1. While this works correctly on images larger than the enclosing div's dimensions, it doesnt work on images which are smaller that the div dimensions. Ideally, I expect irrespective of the image dimensions, the image zooms nonetheless.
2. Right now, there is no control over the extent of zooming. I want that there probably be + and - buttons (something like [this](http://www.activeg.com/agBlog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Untitled.png)) on the bottom of the image which give the user control over the scale of the zoom while showing the current zoom percentage.

I've made a codepen of my case here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gJEdxm

How should these 2 changes be effected? I'm novice at Javascript so not sure how this would work out. Reading the [documentation](https://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/), I see there is a possibility to specify the zoom percentage (`magnify` attribute). Is there someway to give the input to magnify from the UI?